# Error con xamarin forms al crear el apk, ensamblado system.configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Tengo un error para generar el apk, resulta que tengo un proyecto domain (.net framework), un backend con mvc y un api con web api, además del proyecto android e iOs, el error se centra en que en el proyecto principal de xamarin tengo una referencia de ensamblado a `system.configurarion` pues en este proyecto tengo una referencia al proyecto domain... Si quito el ensamblado me genera error...

El problema resulta cuando genero el apk, pues para esto requiero cambiar a modo release y luego compila, ahi genera el error, en el modo debug el compila todo bien, carga la aplicación y todo correcto.

He buscado soluciones pero no he dado con ninguna...
El error es el siguiente

```
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationException' (defined in assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') with scope 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Configuration.ConfigurationException
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   en Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   en MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args) en /Users/runner/runners/2.165.0/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics/Diagnostic.cs:línea 166
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   Proyecto.Android
```

Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Tu problema es cuando solo generas el apk o cuando levantas el proyecto en el emulador o dispositivo fisico.

Comment: el problema resulta cuando genero el apk, pues para esto requiero cambiar a modo release y luego compila, ahi genera el error, en el modo debug el compila todo bien, carga la aplicación y todo correcto,

Comment: Tenes los mismos paquetes instalados en todos los proyectos incluyendo la misma version de xamarin.forms y xamarin.essentials?

Comment: En el Domain, instale el paquete de entity framework xq lo necesitaba, pero este no está instalado en el proyecto de xamarin... en el proyecto de mvc y web api no he instalado ningun paquete.